# Band structure and band index

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Please let me know If my understanding is right.

For a given $\vec{k}$, $H$ is a function of $\vec{k}$ the energies vary discretely for $n$ ie.,the band index.

For a given $n$, we choose all the vectors to lie in the first Brilouin Zone (FBZ), $E_k$ varies continuously, that is the variation of energy for a particular band. So from these energy eigenvalues and eigenstates we could get the number of electronic states available in the band?

I know am going in circles here.
Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: For infinite crystal there's an uncountable number of eigenstates in the given band with index $n$. Each of the eigenstates has its own $\vec k$. What do you mean by the states available in the band?

Comment: the number of states available in a band is equal to the volume of the first Brillouin zone. this is what I read. I dont understand this. So the no of states available in each band is the same? what about the different types of bands the s band,p band etc?the no of states available in each of these bands.

Answer (score 4):

Let's first consider a finite crystal with $M$ cells. By [Bloch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_wave) we have

$$\psi_n(\vec k)=e^{i\vec k\vec x}u_{n,\vec k}(\vec x),$$

where $u$ is periodic with crystal period. Now, for fixed $n$ we have exactly $M$ points in Brillouin zone, each corresponding to some $\vec k$. In some sense, $M$ can be understood as proportional to volume of Brillouin zone, but I'd not use such description.

Now, since $M$ is problem-specific constant, it can't depend on $n$. So, for all bands number of states available is the same.

If we now let $M\to\infty$, then Brillouin zone becomes continuous, and we have uncountably many eigenstates in it, equal to number of states in each band.

Different types of bands you mention — s, p types — are the bands which are formed from the hybridization of single-atom electron states — such naming is usually used in [tight binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_binding) model. As long as you use Bloch theorem to classify states, you still have the same result: number of states is independent of band index.